# Uninstallation of existing Application using WIX

Tags: windows-installer, package

We have rewritten a WIX MSI Package for an existing application. But how do we handle an existing installation that was not installed using WIX Scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your previous installation was already a Windows Installer package, simply implement a [Major Upgrade](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/major_upgrade.htm) in WiX using the [UpgradeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of your previous installation.

If your previous installation was not a Windows Installer package, you will need to handle the removal yourself. In these cases I have used a launch condition to block installation and advise the user to manually remove existing versions via Add/Remove Programs

Comment: But sorry for a basic question, how to find the GUID of the existing app?

Comment: You can download "ORCA MSI Editor", open your MSI in it, go to "Property" table, "ProductCode" property is product GUID.